# Ajax Call timeout

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm currently using a light javascript library to make ajax calls. The library is 'jx'.

And it works fine. But I would like to add a timeout in order to stop the ajax call if there is no response after a certain time. 
I looked around and it doesn't seems there is a timeout parameter like with jquery...

Is there a way to implement a timeout thanks to a pure javascript? Like this :

```
timer = setTimeout('function{stop the call}', 20000);
jx.load(url, function(data){ 
        // get the data
        clearTimeout(timer);
        }
```

I tried that and it's not working well ... is there an other way to do that? 
Or to make the ajax call syn

Comment: Fix your code. Instead of `'function{stop the call}'` it should be `function() { stop the call }`. Also, I would put the timeout after the ajax call.

Comment: The timeout after the ajax call? why? and at the end of the timer how can I stop the call?

Comment: The lib you're using doesn't have a cancel handler, so You won't be able to do it with this library, sry. And, I guess it wouldn't really matter where you put the setTimeout, it's just a personal preference.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8279035/settimeout-on-asynchronous-function

Comment: @PitaJ see my answer, it seems the library stores the `XMLHttpRequest` object into a `http` variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If [this](http://www.openjs.com/scripts/jx/jx.php) is the library you're using, it seems to be possible:

```
var xhr = jx.init();
var timer = setTimeout(function(){ 
    if(xhr && xhr.abort) xhr.abort();
}, 20000);

jx.load(url, function(data){ 
    clearTimeout(timer);
});
```

Comment: Yes I'm using this library :)
I'm gonna try that right now! Thanks you!

Comment: I just added the code you pasted me. It seems like it never calls jx.http.abort(). So I get my error message thanks to the timer and then I get the response from the ajax call.

Comment: Looked at jx source again, and it seems I got it wrong the first time. Could you try the updated code above?

Comment: @GuillaumeleFloch Are you sure you're using the latest version (3.01A)? `jx.init()` is supposed to return the xhr object, but in the [line by line explanation](http://www.openjs.com/scripts/jx/jx.php) they seem to use 3.00A, and `init` returns undefined.

Comment: I'm gonna update the version I think I run an oldest version ... Thanks!

Comment: Ok I have the last version. The 'xhr.abort()' is executed but I stil get the ajax response ...

Comment: I don't think so ... I set the timeout to 5ms ...
Thank you for all your help! 
and a jx.abort() won't work?

Comment: No, the library doesn't provide such a method. My code was trying to call the [`abort` method of the `XMLHttpRequest` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest#abort())