# How to catch an error on a async callback function on outer try/catch block

Tags: javascript, async-await, puppeteer, settimeout, es6-promise

Ok,

So I am using the puppeteer framework and I have an async function that interact with a webpage.
This function clicks and selects and elements of a webpage while it waiting for the traffic of the page to be idle.
This function works most of the time, but sometimes it stalls.

I want to be able to set a timeout so that if the function is taking longer than a certain amount of time, it throws an error and I can run it again.
So far I cannot seem to get this to work because I cannot get the callback function I pass to `setTimeOut()` to 'interact' with the outer function.

My code looks like this:

```
const scrap_webtite = async page => {
 /* scrap the site */
    try{ // catch all
       // set timeout 
        let timed_out_ID = setTimeout(()=> throw "timeOut", 1000);
       // run the async
        let el = await sometimes_stalls_function(page);
       // if function ran finished correcly     
       clearTimeout(timed_out_ID);
        // save el
        save_el(el);
        }
    }catch(e){
       console.error("Something went wrong!", e);
       // this makes the function run again
       // here is where I want to ideally catch the timeout error
        return false
    }
}
```

I have also tried wrapping the `setTimeOut` function in an `Promise` as per [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8279035/settimeout-on-asynchronous-function) and the using the `.then().catch()` callbacks to try to catch the error to no avail.

Apologies if this is a stupid question, thank for you help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you're running into is essentially that the error thrown in [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout) is not related to your function flow, and thus can't be caught there. You can essentially think of the timer's callback function as a "detached" function: the variables from the parent scope will still be available, but you can't `return` a value to the parent directly etc.

To work around this problem you have a few options, [`Promise.race()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/race) is one possible solution. The idea is to first make an async version of a timeout:

```js
const rejectAfter = (timeout) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => reject(), timeout);
  });
};
```

Then extract your business logic out into a separate async function a-la:

```js
const doTheThing = async () => {
  // TODO: Implement
};
```

And finally in your scraping function, use `Promise.race()` to use the result from whichever of the two finishes first:

```js
const scrape = async (page) => {
  try {
    const el = await Promise.race([
      rejectAfter(1000),
      doTheThing()
    ]);
  } catch(error) {
    // TODO: Handle error
  }
}
```

Comment: Woah this look amazing, i did not know there was a Promise.race function! give me sec to try it out.

Answer (score 1):

try turning everything in the `try` block into a promise

```js
const scrap_webtite = async page => {
 /* scrap the site */
    try{ // catch all
        return await new Promise(async(r,j)=>{
            // set timeout 
            let timed_out_ID = setTimeout(()=>j("timeOut"),1000);
            // run the async
            let el = await sometimes_stalls_function(page);
            // if function ran finished correcly     
            clearTimeout(timed_out_ID);
            // save el
            r(save_el(el));
        })
    }catch(e){
        console.error("Something went wrong!", e);
        // this makes the function run again
        // here is where I want to ideally catch the timeout error
        return false
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this will work too! Thank for you answer!

Comment: I just tried your solution solution too! It works great. For anyone who is having a similar problem.

Comment: Since you wrapped the whole code in a Promise the external try can be replaced with .catch and the function become non async (because it can directly return the Promise).
Here the async function is a promise that wait on another promise: just unwrap and return the inner Promise